# Suppose there are two random events, A and B. Given AB = A' B' , what is the result of P(A|B')+P(A'|B), Is that solvable?

Tags: probability

I am wondering if there is any wrong with this question,
I know P(A'| B)+P(A|B) = 1.
I tried some different approaches,
is P(A'|B)+ P(A|B') solvable?

Comment: What exactly is $AB$ and $A'B'$ ?

Comment: And how can they be equal?  ( What does the equality say about the events. )

Comment: By the way, if you meant $A\cap B=A^c\cap B^c$, then it is pretty clear that they are disjoint, therefore they both are equal to $\emptyset$. $A\cap B=\emptyset$ means $A\subseteq B^c$, $A^c\cap B^c=\emptyset$ means that $B^c\subseteq A$, therfore $A=B^c$. Rewritting your expression you get $\mathbb P[A^c|B]+\mathbb P[A|B^c]=\mathbb P[B|B]+\mathbb P[A|A]=1+1=2$.

Comment: Without the requirement $$0<P(B)<1,$$ the exercise is not solvable.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\cap B)$

$=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$, by inclusion-exclusion

$=P(A^c\cap B^c)$, given

$=P(A\cup B)^c$, by D'Morgan

$=1-P(A\cup B)$

$\implies P(A) + P(B) = 1$
$\implies P(A)=1-P(B)=P(B^c) \implies A=B^c \implies B=A^c$

Hence, $P(A|B^c)+P(B|A^c)=1+1=2$